# Stop Access ignoring results where one field is empty

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Access, I have a very simple query that should display all records where the **AD Email Address** field differes from the **AD User Principal Name**

```
SELECT * FROM [Active Directory] WHERE [AD Email Address] <> [AD User Principal Name];
```

This query works with no errors, however I've found that records with an empty **AD Email Address** but a non-empty **AD User Principal Name** are not included.

How can I tweek the query to include these results?

Answer (score 0):

The formal answer is to handle the `NULL` values explicitly.  So, the "correct" answer is:

```
WHERE [AD Email Address] <> [AD User Principal Name] OR
      [AD Email Address] IS NULL AND [AD User Principal Name] IS NOT NULL OR
      [AD Email Address] IS NOT NULL AND [AD User Principal Name] IS NULL
```

Often, this is handled using `NZ()`:

```
WHERE NZ([AD Email Address], "") <> NZ([AD User Principal Name], "")
```

This works when the underlying fields are not empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your query:

`or ([AD Email Address] is null and [AD User Principal Name] is not null)`

which will give your previous results and everything with a blank email address and non-blank principal name.